# How to "dismount" an active partition from Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, mount

I'm using Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS and I have a physical hard drive with 4 partitions:

1) The main Ubuntu system partition (Ext4),

2) The interchange area,

3) My data partition (NTFS), and

4) The old Windows 7 partition (NTFS, of course), which I don't use.

Each time I want to eliminate that Windows partition, the system tells me that "it is mounted" and it doesn't let me to do anything with the partition (not erase, not format, not re-assign).

I've tried with Discs and Gparted and... Nothing!

How can I delete that Windows partition and re-assign it to use it with my data partition?

Comment: If trying to use gparted to delete partition, you must use the live installer, so all partitions are unmounted. It cannot rewrite partition table if any partition is mounted, so you cannot use your working install on same drive. Even with live installer, you may have to swap off as it usually mounts swap and that then needs to be unmounted.

Answer (score 1):

You mean unmount?

You say you've tried Gparted, but did you actually click the "unmount" button?
[image]

Comment: I did it! And now I can not to enter to the system! That partition was mounted into "/tmp" and it had the "boot" flag. I unmounted that partition (with gparted) ad now the system doesn't start and doesn't recognize my username and/or password (I get only a "login error"). How can I do, now? ???

Comment: @Juan  Wait - why did you mount the Windows partition to /tmp?

Comment: I didn't!!! I think I missed something when I installed Ubuntu (maybe I screwed up the Windows partition, unintentionally, of course). However, now I can not to enter to the system (and there is no a Windows option into the startup menu).

Comment: @Juan You probably need to remove the hiber file from windows.

Comment: No. I found the main reason for all this mess: I screwed up the Windows partition when I installed Ubuntu. So, that partition, which I thought was the Windows partition, was an Ubuntu partition. When I got to unmount it, and I erased it, of course Ubuntu couldn't start. I had to re-install Ubuntu and now it 's working (of course, I had to re-install a lot of software). But, it's OK. It was my fault, sorry!!!